# How to apply a trained neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, save

[Python 3.7, Tensorflow] I have trained a neural network. Everything works fine, it learns, but once its done learning it just shuts down and the progress is lost. Now what I want to do is to input new data and see by hand, how good the network does.

I already fiddled around with

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, 'model/model.ckpt')
```

but that always results in a mile-long error report ending with "Unknown Error: Failed to rename 'model/model.ckpt'" etc.

The code in context looks like this:

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    training_data = generate_training_data() # i cut getting training data since its a bit out of context here, but its basically like mnist data

    prediction = neural_network_model(x) # normal, 3-layer feed forward NN
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.square(prediction - y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs+1):
            epoch_loss = 0

            for i in range(10):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = training_data

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})

        saver.save(sess, 'model/model.ckpt')
```

I try to call this trained neural network in main:

```
train_neural_network(x)

X, Y = generate_training_data()

prediction = neural_network_model(x)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:

     saver.restore(sess, 'model/model.ckpt')
     result = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: X})

print(Y, result)
```

Its all in one file so far, but I can also do with two seperate files.

This results in an error, which says the usual python error consisting of its path and ends with
"...in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)" 
before a, what I think, Tensorflow-specific error comes up: 
"Unknown Error: Failed to rename 'model/model.ckpt'" 
and 
"Caused by op 'save_13/SaveV2', defined at:", 
then theres a long, long path, about 87 lines long, 
"Unknown Error" is repeated again.

What I want to have is the printed out label with the from the neural network predicted output. (the print line in the code.)

Unfortunately I have not found anything that works on various internet searches so far, but I feel like it should not be too hard to get this to work.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look in the folder where your model outputs the checkpoints (/model), you should see 3 separate files per each save: model.ckpt-xxx.data, model.ckpt-xxx.index and model.ckpt-xxx.meta, where xxx is the ID of the checkpoint appended by Tensorflow.

When you want to restore a certain checkpoint, you have to add the ID as well, because typically several checkpoints of the same network are being created during training so that we can re-train the network later if necessary.

So I would take a look in the model folder and double check the file name, my guess is 
`saver.restore(sess, 'model/model.ckpt-0')` would do the trick if you only created one checkpoint.

Comment: Yes, I see the files. I have the following files in it:
- checkpoint
- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.index.tempstate13666753728790215124
- model.ckpt.meta
 --- 
Unfortunately it did not work by adding -0 to either the save or the restore line.
Any ideas?

Comment: restore. it gives the following error: {   NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Key Variable_600 not found in checkpoint
  [[node save_49/RestoreV2 (defined at my_path/neural_network.py:120) ]]   }

Comment: Are the two files (main and train_neural_network) in the same folder? It seems to me that Tensorflow cannot find the checkpoint in the folder you specified in the main file and so either the file name or the directory might be the culprit.

Comment: Yes, they are even in the same file. Sorry if my structure caused confusion. The model folder is in the same folder as main.